# How can I automatically change spaces to underscores in the file save dialog box?

Tags: files, batch-rename

I am often saving documents from my Windows-using coworkers, and the filenames usually contain spaces.

For example, I'm always renaming

```
Important CEO Spreadsheet v2.xls
```

to...

```
Important_CEO_Spreadsheet_v2.xls
```

Is there a way to script the Save As dialog box to automatically detect whitespace and replace it with underscores?

Comment: If this is something that can't be addressed at the operating-system level, and must instead be addressed at the application-level, then this might not be answerable.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of anything that would change that in the box but you could run:

```
rename 's/ /_/g' *.xls
```

... in the directory that these are being saved to. You could save that as an alias in `~/.bash_aliases` like: `alias underscore="rename 's/ /_/g' *.xls"` and then just run `underscore`.

Or you could create a new shortcut/link on your desktop that did something similar. It would probably need to run through Bash so you'd have a command like:

```
bash -c "cd yourXlsDir; rename 's/ /_/g' *.xls"
```

Comment: This would be helpful in the Downloads folder, since many documents are downloaded from web-based tools like the company wiki. However, I'm hoping for a solution that addresses the dialog box.

Comment: @Oli: Instead of `rename 's/ /_/' *.xls` one could consider `rename 's/ /_/g' *.txt` because the **g** would take care of more than one space in the filename. Using `-n` with `rename` would do a dry run to see what the result will be without actually modifying anything.

Comment: `rename 's/ +/_/g' *.xls` in case there are some files with more than one space between words.

Comment: @Sylwester That's not needed as it's a global replace (it'll find it in the next scan) but *it will* replace each space with an underscore. Multiple concurrent underscores might be undesirable.